# Not able to fetch data in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\ExportPagetoPDFinASP.Net\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cookbook";
    cmd.Connection = con;

 cmd.ExecuteReader();

}
```

Not able to fetch data. i don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

[`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would return you a DataReader, you need to iterate it and get rows from your command.

You can also use a `DataTable` to fill the rows from DataReader like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

You can have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\ExportPagetoPDFinASP.Net\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cookbook";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

Consider using [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) with your Connection and Command objects.

You can iterate rows returned from DataReader like:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0])); //prints first column
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string Log(int userResult)
    {
        string result = "result saved";


        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXX;InitialCatalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.setCalculatorResult";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RESULT", userResult);

                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();

                int rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowCount == 0)
                    result = "there was an error";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and also consider using procs